# NTP Multicast configuration

Tags: linux, centos, time, ntp, multicast

I'm trying to get NTP multicast set up between a few computers. Right now I'm getting NTP multicast packets from a computer that I have neither access to nor information on (let's call that A) that is serving as a stratum 4 NTP multicast server and I'm trying to get a few computers' time to synchronize to that.

The computers that I'm trying to sync (let's call them B) are running CentOS6.4 and use ntpd version 4.2.4p8. B can receive the multicast packet from A but can't access A otherwise (can't ping). From B, A is the only NTP server available. `ntpd` is set to start when computer boots up and is called with the "-g" flag. From the NTP multicast packets I gathered that A is sending to multicast address "224.0.1.1" from IP address "192.168.1.103"

Below is ntp.conf from B:

```
tinker panic 0
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
keys /etc/ntp/keys
restrict 192.168.1.103 kod nomodify noquery notrap
multicastclient 224.0.1.1
disable auth
```

Right now computer B receives NTP packets from A, and given enough time, `ntpstat` on B will show that it is synced to A. If time on B is essentially (within seconds) the same as that on A when I started ntpd on B, then if I change time on B after `ntpstat` shows "synchronized" on B, time gets changed back within about ~30minutes. If I change the time on B to be minutes different from A or greater and start ntpd on B, ntpstat will eventually say "synchronized" but the time will still be wrong and will not change at all (so far waited for up to 3 days). Using `ntpq -pn` shows the offset as something in the tens (10~40) while the time on B off by something that's well into minutes or hours.

I'm hoping to get B set up so that even if the time on B is different from A by some arbitrarily large amount when it syncs to A it will adjust back. I'm wondering if there's a way to either configure ntpd on B to be able to do that or to have something that parses the multicast packets from A and either gives me a correct timestamp or the time difference between A and B.

So far I've tried `ntpdate` and `sntp`, neither worked. I've also tried getting the timestamps using `ntpq`, but that turned out to be not helpful (either 0 or simply local time).

Comment: You should have provided some ntp status outputs. Note that `ntpd` will **not** correct arbitrary amounts of clock offset (as a "security" measure). Also using `ntpdate` on a multicast address may be "tricky" at least. Finally: If the existing answer helped you to solve the issue, you should "accept" it.

Answer (score 1):

- Please try to remove "nopeer" flag from the "restrict" statement. If "nopeer" is not removed multicast connection cannot be established.
- You can also disable all other restrict statements except the default one and keep just the lines as followings below:

> driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
>
> restrict -4 default notrap nomodify
>
> broadcast 224.0.1.1
>
> disable auth
>
> multicastclient 224.0.1.1

Also after the configuration it is needed to restart ntp service:

> service ntp restart